# Convert perl script to bash

Tags: bash, scripting, perl

The following script it's about monitoring some logs, the $timestamp is at log at every line that something happens.

```
Example:
03:19:13.4 Begin summary update for ads.doc.inventory.InventoryItemSummary
03:19:33.9 CronServer:: DailyJob ads.tools.UpdateSummaries@17c5d6cf failed with exception ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
ads.util.AppError: Cannot create UnitName from keys: Each
at ads.db.DBObjectDefault.createFromKeys(DBObjectDefault.java:42)
at ads.db.DBTable.createFromKeys(DBTable.java:227)
at ads.db.DBValue.getValue(DBValue.java:621)
at ads.dbmanager.DBObjectsManager.initObjects(DBObjectsManager.java:400)
at ads.dbmanager.DBObjectsManager.reload(DBObjectsManager.java:447)
at ads.dbmanager.DBObjectsManager.loadFromStore(DBObjectsManager.java:497)
at ads.doc.inventory.InventoryItemSummary.refreshSince(InventoryItemSummary.java:173)
at ads.db.DBSummaryTable.refreshAll(DBSummaryTable.java:67)
at ads.tools.CronServer$DailyThread.run(CronServer.java:271)
[SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:354)
at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.invoke(Call.java:248)
at ads.support.SupportCall.call(SupportCall.java:56)
at ads.tools.SupportThread.run(SupportThread.java:101)
03:46:42.5 Periodic support request failed: ads.support.SupportException: Error opening socket: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
06:31:36.1 Upload failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:/tmp/cygwin1.dll (No such file or directory)
08:01:08.0 connect from /172.22.3.28
```

I have this perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

my $timestamp = qr/^\d+:\d+:\d+/;

my $block = "";
my $exception = 0;
while (<STDIN>) {

if ($block) {
# $_ is the current input line in perl.
    if ($_ =~ $timestamp) {
        print "\n\n***EXCEPTION***\n$block" if $exception;
        $block = "";
        $exception = 0;
    }
# This isn't actually a second regexp, it's a substring search.
# But you could use a regexp.
    $exception = 1 if (index($_,"Exception") >= 0);
    $block .= $_;
    next;
}
$block = $_ if ($_ =~ $timestamp);
}
```

and I want to convert it to bash script.

Here's what I've done so far but didn't work,
    #!/bin/bash

```
timestamp=^[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]

block=""

exception=false

except=.*Exception.*

while read line
do

if [[ -z $block ]] ;
   then

    if [[ $line =~ $timestamp ]]
       then

            if [[ $exception=false ]]
               then
                     echo "\n\n***EXCEPTION***\n$block"
            fi
block=""
exception=false
    fi

    if [[ $line =~ $except ]]
       then
            exception=true
    fi

block=$block$line

fi

if [[ $line =~ $timestamp ]]
   then
    block=$line
fi

done
```

Any help with that?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Bash doesn't handle regular expressions natively.  What you propose is a lot more complex and involves using external commands.  I wouldn't go so far as to say it's impossible, but it's almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: The output is empty with the bash script!

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns @Ghodmode.

Comment: Looking at this are you trying to parse your log file and just get a list of all exceptions and associated stack traces?  Or are you looking to preserve the log and just offset the stack traces with your `***EXCEPTION***` markers?

Comment: Yes, exactly this. As input is a log file and I want to print all the block (timestamp to timestamp) if inside the block there is the word exception.

Comment: @Mat Well I'll be damned!  I stand corrected. :) I started learning Bash before the `=~` operator was introduced and I guess haven't kept my knowledge up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

1. you have to quote filename pattern metacharacters like `*` and `[`

   ```
   timestamp='^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]'
   except='.*Exception.*'
   ```
2. the `test` command (otherwise known as `[[`) operates on the number of arguments it receives. It is therefore very sensitive to whitespace:

   ```
       if [[ $exception = false ]]
   ```
3. there's a major logic error: you unset the `block` variable inside the `[[ -z $block ]]` block: once `block` is non-zero it can never be unset.
4. Why are you rewriting a working script?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the following solution is closer to the original script than what I initially wrote (it checks the whole block body, not just the first line, for the word “Exception”):

```
block=()
newblock() {
    [[ ${block[*]} = *Exception* ]] && printf '%s\n' '' '' '***EXCEPTION***' "${block[@]}"
    block=("$line")
}
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
    ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9]\ *)
            newblock
            ;;
    (*)
            block+=("$line")
            ;;
    esac
done
newblock
```

Comment: You're the best, works fine, but I don't understand the block[], (*). Can't understand how it checks the whole block body and how block is defined.

Comment: @CTs `[[ ${block[*]} = *Exception* ]]` checks the whole block body. `block` is an array, every array item is a line.

Comment: Inside the while loop you insert every line at the array (block+=("$line"))? What is (*) at the while loop?
At the newblock method, block=("$line") what exactly does?
Sorry for all the questions, but I'm new at bash and first time come across with array!

Comment: `(*)` belongs to `case` and is, basically, the equivalent of the `default` statement in C `switch`. And `x+=(y)` appends to the array x, while `x=(y)` sets the array x empty before appending y.